# How to remove moire pattern using opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, camera, projector

I'm trying to realize a projector-camera system. I want to detect the finger on my desk.But the moire pattern has become a huge problem. I can't use background subtraction to find the contour of my finger.How can I remove the moire pattern?
[image]

Comment: This might help- http://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?t=158242

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? ...and, if you wound up mothballing the project, have you already tried adapting [this PyOpenCV denoising tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d5/d69/tutorial_py_non_local_means.html)?